# iCloud causing phone to crash whilst making a call

Tags: ios, icloud, iphone

I have an iPhone 3GS, and I recently installed iOS 5 and set up iCloud. However, since then my phone crashes when I make a phone call (after about 2-3 minutes). I tried deleting my iCloud account to see if this rectified the problem but I lost all my contacts. Can anyone suggest any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Downgrade to iOS 4. The 3GS is rather slow with iOS 5, so you will just find more problems as time goes on. Or do a restore of iOS 5 and see if that helps.

Comment: This does not sound like an iCloud issue, and you have not proven it to be one. I suggest removing or changing the word "iCloud" in your question title.

Comment: Apart from losing your contacts, you did't say if this actually worked and stopped crashing.  I can't see a link, but more info is probably required.

Answer (score 1):

Those problems were reported by multiple owners. Apple claims to have solved those failing phone calls with the current iOS 5.1 update. Have you updated yet?

Comment: they havent fixed it with 5.1 just updated to it cant hold a call fro longer than 5 mins

Comment: Have you tried what jbharper2 suggested (restore your device)?

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to guess that this issue in fact has little to nothing to do with iCloud and more to do with your upgrade to iOS 5.  As Paul mentioned, iOS 5 is a little slow on a 3GS, but that doesn't necessarily mean that you're out of the iOS 5 game just yet.  I'll assume that you've tried the basic steps of power cycling the phone and resetting the phone (press and hold the sleep/wake button and the home button simultaneously until you see the apple logo) and are ready to move on from there.

The first step is to re-install iOS 5.  In iTunes, sync and back up your phone and then hit the Restore Button on the iPhone Summery page.  You can then restore from the back up you just made.  Once your device is back up and running, give her a whirl and see if the crashing has stopped.

If your phone app is still crashing after a restore, it's possible that it's due to corrupt information stored somewhere in your backup.  If this is the case, you'll need to try restoring your phone again, but this time setting it up as a new device instead of restoring from your backup.  This will frequently clear up stubborn issues.  Be aware, while all of your media, calendars, contacts, apps and such will be recoverable from your computer and/or from the cloud, you will loose your camera roll (if it's not synced to your computer) as well as call logs, SMS history and any 3rd party app data that doesn't have it's own syncing mechanism.  If any of this data is important to you, I suggest looking into an app such as [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) or [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to save this information before hand.